# How to force Mathematica to integrate only over the domain given by (few) step functions?

Tags: numerical-integration

Consider the function `f[x,y,z,...]*UnitStep[g1[x,y,z,...]]*UnitStep[g2[x,y,z]]`.

the variables x,y,z… are defined into the ranges $\{x_{1},x_{2}\},\{y_{1},y_{2}\},...$, while UnitStep functions cut off the domains where the function f is real.

I need to integrate it over all variables. If I use simple code

```
NIntegrate[f[x,y,z,...]*UnitStep[g1[x,y,z,...]]*UnitStep[g2[x,y,z]],{x,x1,x2},{y,y1,y2},Method->"MonteCarlo"]
```

then the result is zero. The reason is that on most of the domain the function `f[x,y,z,...]*UnitStep[g1[x,y,z,...]]*UnitStep[g2[x,y,z]]` is identically zero due to UnitSteps, and Monte-Carlo [method obviously has problems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183217/quasi-monte-carlo-method-gives-zero-for-the-following-example) with giving correct value.

Is there a method of evaluation of the integral only in regions defined by UnitStep functions?

Comment: well, don't use Monte Carlo.

Comment: Can `Reduce[UnitStep[g1[x,y,z,...]]*UnitStep[g2[x,y,z]==1,{x,y,z,...}]` give you a sufficiently simple set of bounds for x,y that you can then integrate over that domain? Without the code it is difficult to give any more precise answer

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : any other method does not evaluate the integral.

Comment: @Bill : thank you. Do you know how to use the results of Reduce as the integration region?

Comment: @Bill : thank you. Do you know how to use the results of Reduce as the integration region without explicit inserting (there is a lot of conditions and it is complicated to insert them)?

Comment: @Bill : it turns out that Reduce[...] takes very large amount of time (I can not even wait for finishing).

Comment: Without seeing your actual code, particularly if your code is very complicated, there is likely no way that anyone can guess what to tell you to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is one approach that might work on your problem.  You could replace the `UnitStep` functions with regions.  Mathematica might be able to deal with the integral more effectively.

```
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < z^2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
NIntegrate[Exp[x]/(1 + y + z), {x, y, z} ∈ ℛ]
(* 0.182439 *)
```

Comment: He can just use non-Monte-Carlo methods in his original integral computation specification.

Comment: @AntonAntonov : another methods don't work, probably because of very large time of determination of the region.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you use a non-Monte-Carlo method you get the result quickly without messages.

```
In[971]:= Block[{xmax = 100, ymax = 100},
 NIntegrate[UnitStep[9 - x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}]
 ]

Out[971]= 7.06858
```

(Using the integral in the question you linked as ["Monte-Carlo having problems"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183217/quasi-monte-carlo-method-gives-zero-for-the-following-example).)