# Double integral problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate this double integral using Mathematica:

$$\iint_D x^3 y^3 \ln(1+x^2+y^2) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y,$$

where

$$D=\left\{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leqslant 4, \; x,y \geqslant 0 \right\}.$$

I know how to calculate a definite double integral in Mathematica, but I am not sure how to do it with region $D$.

Comment: Please include Mathematica code for what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: check these must answer! https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183223/how-to-force-mathematica-to-integrate-only-over-the-domain-given-by-few-step-f

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240780/calculating-double-integral-bounded-by-domain-in-wolfram-alpha-notebook

Comment: reg = ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 < 4, {x, y} > 0}, {x, y}]; ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 4 && {x, y} > 0, {x, y}]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Integrate[
 x^3*y^3*Log[1 + x^2 + y^2]*
  Boole[x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && x >= 0 && 
    y >= 0], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}]

(*  5/288 (-28 + 153 Log[5])  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Alternatively ``Integrate[
 x^3*y^3*Log[1 + x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] 
  Disk[{0, 0}, 2, {0, Pi/2}]]`` can also be used.